# How to turn off prettier derived eslint errors in vscode?

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint, prettier

I love what prettier does in tandem with eslint. I am glad that we can't push up misformatted code without errors, but is there a way to turn off the complaints in vscode? I don't need vscode giving things a red underline because I hit enter and now something is on a new line that the formatter doesn't like, especially when I have format on save. I would guess that the only solution to this is to remove all linting related to formatting and just have things fixed with the running of formatting in pre commit hooks and github actions...

To add onto this. I think the errors I'm getting come from this plugin included in .eslintrc:

"plugin:prettier/recommended"

When I turn it off the errors go away. My preference would be to find a way to hide these errors in vscode while keeping this plugin

Comment: I'm not aware of there being a way to do this. I looked through all the settings in VS Code and contributed by the prettier extension that contained the substring "`problem`", and didn't see anything that looked like it would allow one to achieve this.

Comment: Damn, well thanks for looking. I forgot about this and have just been dealing with the issue for months now xD half the time I manually fix some of the prettier issues just so the errors go away, since I don't always want to save when I have a work in progress that wouldn't compile

Comment: Related: [How can I easily toggle display of problem underlining in VS Code editor panels?](/q/74753185/11107541)